# Issue with jQuery data

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I'm struggling a little. I'm attempting to utilize the cool feature of assigning a custom attribute to an element. However it isn't working.

Basically, I'm trying to assign multiple elements to the TR element identifying information in that row. Here is what it looks like:

```
for (x=0; x< theData.length; x++)
{
    // create table row
    var selector = "wc_" + wID + "_row_" + x;

    oRow = document.createElement("TR");
    oRow.setAttribute("id", selector);
    tBodyO.appendChild(oRow);
    var rowCount = 0;
    var identCnt = 0;
    for (var index in theData[x])
    {
        identCnt = 0;
        if (hasIdentify)
        {
            for (y=0; y < theIdent.length; y++)
            {
                console.log("ROW: "+x+" , checking: "+index+"  ===  "+theIdent[y]["data_name"]);
                if (index === theIdent[y]["data_name"])
                {
                    myrow = $("#" + selector);
                    //myrow.attr("test","works");
                    console.log("ident Dataname: "+theIdent[y]["data_name"]+ "  identify:"+theIdent[y]["identify"]+"   value: "+theData[x][index]);
                    jQuery.data( myrow, "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
                    alert(myrow.data("test"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've left out some code that's not really relevant, but I hope you get the picture. What I'm trying to do is this:

I have an array that contains "identity" information about a particular row of data. It can have 0, 1 or more such identity pieces. I want to store these as a custom data attribute on the `<TR>` element.

Each data will have a distinct `key` (example: `i_0_1` where `0` is the data row number and `1` is the identity counter)
However, I can't get this to work. I've tried lots of alternatives even trying to resort to `.attr()` with no luck. What am I doing wrong??

I'm getting an alert that says `undefined`. When I try the `myrow.attr("test","works");` route I can see the attribute in the DOM. Why won't the `data()` way work for me?

Comment: What does it do instead? Note that setting `data()` will ***not*** actually set an attribute or property on the element; jQuery stores this data in an internal cache, and merely *maps* it to the element you selected. Also (this is irrelevant to you problem, but just an FYI), you should be declaring your variables using `var`, otherwise they will end up being implicit globals, which are *bad*.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what the problem is. I guess after reading the docs on jQuery.data() I didn't see anyone really clearly come out and say:

You will not see the data info in the DOM - element when you look at the source.

To the credit of everyone here, they did tell me, I just didn't know what I was reading (now that I know what is expected)

Matt wrote:
"ill not actually set an attribute or property on the element; jQuery stores this data in an internal cache, and merely maps it to the element you selected"

Although after playing around with the .attr() and setAttribute() functions I just became more confused.

Thanks everyone!